# Nested attributes wouldn't save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models one Topic and Topic_Content.

With the following code

**Route**

```
  resources :topics do 
    resources :topic_contents
  end
```

**Topic**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :topic_content
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic_content
end
```

**TopicContent**

```
class TopicContent < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :topics
end
```

**Controller**

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

 def new 
   @topic = Topic.new 
 end

 def create
   # render text: params[:topic].inspect
   @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
   @topic.save
 end

 private 

 def topic_params
   params.require(:topic).permit(:title, topic_content_attributes: [:text])
 end

end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @topic do |f| %>
<%= f.label 'Topic:' %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.fields_for :topic_contents do |tf| %>
<%= tf.label :text %>
<%= tf.text_area :text %> 
<% end %>    
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The **title** will be saved correct in the topic table but the topic_content(**text**) wouldn't saved in the database, and I couldn't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Rails expert, but I'm certain you need to build the association in your controller.

In your new and edit actions you need to have:

```
def new 
  @topic = Topic.new 
  @topic_content = @topic.build_topic_content
end
```

Because this is a has_one/belongs_to you need to have it look that way.  If it was a many association you'd build it with something like @topic_content = @topic.topic_contents.build.

I'm pretty sure it's just a matter of building the association in the right controller, which, I believe, for you, is the topic controller.

Comment: Thx, for the fast answer it helps me a lot!. One problem is left for me. It sets the foreign key correct but **:text** not.

Answer (score 1):

Your view should be as follow:

```
f.fields_for :topic_content do |content_fields|
                          ^
```